# How to use 3-D array in OpenCL kernel?

Tags: opencl, multidimensional-array

I am new to OpenCL. I have worked with OpenCL kernel with 1-D data. But when I tried to pass a 3-D pointer, it fails to build the kernel. To be specific I'm getting **CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE**. Here's the pseudo code for the kernel I'm trying to build -

```
__kernel void 3D_Test(__global float ***array)
{

x = get_global_id(0);
y = get_global_id(1);
z = get_global_id(2);

array[x][y][z] = 10.0;

}
```

Could anyone give me an idea on what's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check the build log, get it with clGetProgramBuildInfo.

Comment: You might also have a look at the Image3D type, supported in OpenCL 1.1, which lets you store and pass 3D arrays quite easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not valid OpenCL C (that's why it doesn't compile), for a 3D array, you will have to use a linearlized version of that array, just create a normal array of appropiate size (sizeX * sizeY * sizeZ) and index it this way:

```
int index = x + y * sizeX + z * sizeX * sizeY;
```

Other option is to use a 3D image with clCreateImage3D